# Передача с клиента на сервер JSon коллекции

Tags: c#, jquery, knockoutjs

Проблема состоит в следующем, на клиенте есть функция передачи модели (Model)

```
            self.getModel = function () {
            return {                    
                **TypeMembers: self.selectedTypevalues(),**               
                SelectedFrequency: self.selectedFrequency(),
                MembershipId: self.membershipId(),
                Customer: $('#customers-list').data('kendoAutoComplete').value(),
            };
```

Проблема как раз состоит с передачей **TypeMembers**

На контроллере в результате получения они приходят viewModel.TypeMembers с null по ID и Name

```
 private IEnumerable<ReportItem> GetGridItems(ReportViewModel viewModel)
 {            
        var membertypeValues = viewModel.TypeMembers.Select(zx => 
        zx.Id.ToInteger());
 }
```

Как нужно преобразовать на стороне клиента чтобы на сервере получить нормальную json-читаемую коллекцию?

Comment: Покажите объект (как JSON) из `self.getModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Нужен корректный мэпппинг:

```
            var arr = self.selectedTypevalues();
            var mappedTypeMembers = $.map(arr, function (value, key) {
              console.log(value.id);
              return  {id : value.id, name : value.name};
            });
```